# Meaning of different command line prompts in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

I have the following code from my command line...

```
psql (9.1.10)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# CREATE DATABASE exampledb
postgres-#
```

After I entered the CREATE DB command the prompt changed from ending with "=#" to "-#". I would like to know what this change means and what the implications are for receiving and processing commands.

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-PROMPTING

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks for the link! It got me started towards an answer.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I now realize that the "postgres=#" prompt is a fresh prompt waiting for the start of a new command, while the "postgres-#" is the result of hitting enter after typing a command that does not end with a semicolon.

The semicolon denotes the end of a command, so pressing enter without a terminating ";" suggests to postgres that you would like to continue writing your command on a new line.

Inserting a semicolon at any point and pressing enter will return you to the original prompt.

Comment: Also a `postgres(#` indicates you have an open parenthesis, and it will show quoting with `postgres'#`, `postgres"#`, and `postgres$#` prompts.  Finally if you were not a superuser your prompt would end in `>` (like `postgres=>`).